# Are answers duplicate if they use different aliases of the same command?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1029803/380318) came up in the First Posts queue. It uses the Windows `rd` command to accomplish the task in the question. The accepted answer (from 2010), however, uses `rmdir` with the same parameters. `rd` and `rmdir` mean the same thing on Windows, so the two commands literally do the same thing. The accepted answer has additional useful information, while the answer in question doesn't really, but it somehow got an upvote anyway. In my opinion, the `rd` answer should have been a comment on the accepted answer, but the new user has insufficient rep.

What should I do with such answers?

Comment: If it's the same command, and it does exactly the same thing, then it's just repeating the same information.

Comment: @Ramhound That makes sense. Should I downvote the answer? Should I flag it? (It has *two* upvotes now.)

Comment: When I see a question that doesn't add very much I indicate as much with a vote and leave a comment.

Comment: There is one extra bit of information in this case--the alias itself. I would personally like that extra bit of information converted to a comment, or possibly added as a footnote on the original question.